# Is it possible to hook data from S3 to RoR driven website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, amazon-s3, reporting, dashboard

I am ding some processing on business data using EMR and my output is stored in S3. I need to setup a reporting dashboard to surface up this processed data. I was looking into various options and seems Ruby on Rails is good framework to start with.

Is it possible to hook data from S3 to RoR driven website? If yes, how ?

Any pointer would be helpful. Do let me know if there are any other open source platform which I can use.

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible to upload and download data from s3, and it's fairly simple to set up.  Rails is fully capable but possibly not the simplest solution.  If you plan on using heroku here is a good post http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3.  There are lots of other good tutorials online.  This is a fairly open ended question, if you have any specific questions please post.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll probably want to consider, is using Paperclip (or another similar gem) to store the data on S3. Within your application, you can then locate/compute the data you'll need to display through your Paperclip-based model, then have Paperclip retrieve and load the data you need.

The nice thing about such a solution is that it's completely transparent for you (as a user AND as a developer): you're just working with your objects, and they get stored/retrieved form S3 as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Both Heroku and Engineyard (probably the two largest cloud providers for rails) use S3 as the backend, so using these providers could be great.

Heroku tends to be more 'out-of-the-box' so I think EngineYard with CLI(Command Line) access would be better suited to your needs.

More info on the two at
[Heroku vs EngineYard: which one is more worth the money?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197197/heroku-vs-engineyard-which-one-is-more-worth-the-money) and
http://mikemainguy.blogspot.com/2011/08/heroku-is-bus-engineyard-is-car.html and
http://www.cuberick.com/2010/04/engine-yard-vs-heroku-getting-started.html has more on setup / cost.

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible. Use the fog gem.

I have to not recommend you use carrierwave or paperclip for your specific needs here. They're good when you are uploading the data initially, but in your case you're accessing existing data. Just use fog to connect to s3 directly.